# PHP Remove Non-URLs From Array

Tags: php, arrays, filter

I am scraping a list of URLs from a website with regex in PHP and use the following code to clean up the results.

```
// Echo each found result
foreach ($matches as $val) {
    $results[] = GetStringBetween($val[1], "http://", "&");
}

$results = array_unique($results);
$results = array_filter($results);
```

It works however the problem is it gives some unwanted results like:

```
ed_search?q=product
```

Is there any way to filter and keep only valid urls in an array?

I need the URLs to start with either www., http:, https:

Comment: Have you looked at http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php parse_url?

Comment: first you'd have to define what a valid url is. `href="kittens.jpg"` is a "valid url", even though it doesn't contain a protocol, host, or path...

Comment: I want it to start with either www., http:, https:

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = "xxxxx";

if( filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)  !== FALSE )
{
    // validated as an url
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

Comment: Your code does not seem to do anything, i tried a unset($val[1]); in the if statement also and it does not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
$urls = array_filter($urls, function ($url) {
    return filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.